# How can I improve my post here so that it is not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

My post here:

Book recommendation: [Book on condensed matter physics focusing on numerical method in quantum system [duplicate]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318141/)

How can I further improve my post so that it is not a duplicate?

Comment: FWIW, at this time there are 3 reopen votes. Two more and it will open. If there aren't enough additional votes, then it will stay closed. Maybe the only advice I could give is to really focus on the fact you are really looking for numerical approaches and not theoretical/experimental. But, let the reopen cycle run its course and see what happens from there.

Comment: @tpg2114 thank you very much for your help and advice. I wish you the best. But I will be off for a while to focus on my thing so I may not be able to read these two posts again soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking. But in this case, I don't believe there is any way to change your question such that it is not a duplicate, without making it an entirely different question.

Resource recommendations are treated somewhat specially, and one of the ways that they are treated specially is that the rules for what constitutes a duplicate are broader than normal questions. In particular, a recommendation question which shares its general topic and general level with another one is considered a duplicate. In your case, your question's general topic is condensed matter physics and its level is what we might call intermediate. There is already a recommendation question seeking intermediate-level condensed matter books. Yours is therefore a duplicate of that question.

What you could do is ask the actual conceptual question you would hope to answer by reading the books. That would presumably be a fine question for this site.

Comment: I'm not an expert in condensed physics, but isn't asking for something specifically about the numerical methods making it a whole new topic already? If somebody asked for a set of books on fluid dynamics, that would be an entirely different set than I would give for a recommendation on numerical methods used in fluid dynamics. In fact, I can't think of a single book that I would consider an overlap.

Comment: @tpg2114 But the request is for a book for someone not knowing any condensed matter physics.  It were different if it were about books for someone knowing condensed matter, and then wanting to learn specifically numerical methods.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That might make it a bad/impossible question, but certainly not a duplicate. It's possible there is no book that teaches condensed matter physics at the same time it teaches numerical methods. And that's a different situation than being duplicate.